# Restarting an updated powershell script

Tags: powershell, continuous-deployment, restart

I'm making a makeshift CI/CD system for my app, the app stops itself when notified of a push to a Github repo and the script automatically runs `git pull` to bring in changes and some more commands depending on the things that changed. Some of the changes could be to the script.

I want the script to restart itself, without infinite nesting where it could hog resources.

```
While ($true) {
    git pull
    # check for changes...
    If ($runScriptChanged) {
        Break
    }
    node index.js
}
# ???
```

<sup>Omitted error-checking parts and other updating parts for brevity</sup>

- Calling itself will probably work, but again, it could hog resources infinitely until stopped
- Making a new file to run the above script still leaves a file in the repo that cannot be updated automatically
- `Start-Process` is the best I've found for this, but I'm not sure about it's behavior on Linux

  - [When does the launching shell close?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3#example-9-create-a-detached-process-on-linux) Is it the same as on Windows with `-NoNewWindow` (where it will stay open, as long as there's something using it)? (Currently I'm running it on Windows Server, so compatibility with Linux isn't a big concern, but it is nice to have)

Which way should I use? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using PowerShell jobs and the [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) cmdlet. It will start your processes in the background and also has some monitoring and management capabilities using other `-Job` cmdlets such as `Get-Job`, `Wait-Job`,`Stop-Job`, etc.

See [about_Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs) for more information.